# CS0103 Переменная не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#, unity3d

Cake.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cake : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj_text;
    Score score_sc;
    void Start(){
    }
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Score score_sc;
        score_sc = obj_text.GetComponent<Score>();
        Destroy(gameObject);
        score = score + 1;
    }
}
```

В Score.cs я только создал переменную score.

[image]

Помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так ты же не объявил переменную score, поэтому и ругается

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    int score; // объявление переменной

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
       score = score + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так у меня переменная из другого скрипта который на другом файле: public GameObject obj_text;
Score score_sc;
score_sc = obj_text.GetComponent<Score>();

Comment: @farkon00 Ну тогда подумайте логически, хоть немного перед тем, как задавать вопрос. Как мы должны, по-вашему, догадаться, что в вашем проекте? Если переменная в другом скрипте, то наверно надо через этот скрипт и обращаться (`score_cs.score ++`)?